# awk change datetime format

Tags: json, regex, linux, awk, sed

I have huge amount of files where each string is a json with incorrect date format. The format I have for now is `2011-06-02 21:43:59` and what I need to do is to add `T` in between to transform it to ISO format `2011-06-02T21:43:59`.

Can somebody, please, point me to some one liner solution? Was struggling with this for 2 hours, but no luck.

Comment: show a sample, 5 or 10 items in a file should be enough.

Comment: show us a sample file!

Comment: It is unclear what is meant by _"amount of files where each string is a json"_. Do you mean that each file contains multiple JSON objects?

Comment: Why is the number of lines a requirement in your requested solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to be the working solution:

`sed -i -r 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})/\1T\2/g' myfiles`

- `-i` to process files
- `-r` is to switch on extended regular expression
- `([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})` - is for date
- - the space between date and time in source data
- `([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})` - is for time

Answer (score 1):

`sed` will come to your rescue, with a simple `regex`:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\) /\1T/g' file > file.new
```

or, to modify the file in place:

```
sed -i 's/\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\) /\1T/g' file
```

*Example*

```
echo '2011-06-02 21:43:59' | sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\) /\1T/g'
2011-06-02T21:43:59
```

Read more about regexes here: [Regex Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)

Comment: That seems to be not working, please, see my solution.

Comment: @mr.nothing: it did work for me (tried it on Ubuntu 12.04).  What is the error you are getting?  I have posted an example output in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also with `awk`, you can match group with `gensub` :

```
awk '{
    print gensub(/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\s+([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})/,
        "\\1T\\2",
        "g");
}' data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '2011-06-02 21:43:59' | awk 'sub(/ /,"T")'
2011-06-02T21:43:59
```